# Synology Mac OS X startup mounting folders via NFS

Tags: startup, automount

A couple of years or so ago, I modified a script, according to a forum message, which would (I assume) automount the folders found on my Synology server, ie web, video, public, music, photo at startup time. This would then show these folders in the Finder window. I no longer have the Synology server running so as a result, whenever I restart my IMac (OS X 10.7.5) there are messages that pop up for each folder: "There was a problem connecting to the server "192.168.xxx.xxx". Now I can't remember what script I changed so I can comment out these commands. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your User Preferences to be sure these items are not checked in the "Mount at login" box?

If they are, it's a simple matter of deleting them from the list once you have authenticated to unlock the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're referring to `/etc/auto_master`.